# SQL: disjoint select to one table

Tags: sql

Good time.

Say, there is a table that contains data about exam results:

```
                EXAM_RESULTS
| ID | EXAM_TYPE | PERSON_ID | EXAM_RESULT |
```

A student can try to pass the concrete exam multiple times, so it is possible for one student to have four rows in the above table: three for fail results and one for success. I need to select all students that have not passed the concrete type of exam yet.

Please suggest, how to do it or where to read about such a trick.

**EDIT**:
Sample records:

```
| 1 | SDA | 111 | FAIL |
| 2 | SDA | 111 | FAIL |
| 3 | SDA | 111 | PASSED |
| 4 | SDA | 222 | FAIL |
| 4 | SDA | 222 | FAIL |
```

According to the task the query must select only the 222 person cause he have not passed the SDA exam (111 person eventually passed)

Comment: can you give sample records and your desired result? is `ID` auto_incremented column? what is `Exam_type` column?

Comment: isnt it as simple as two `where` conditions for `examtype` and `examresult`?? sample records will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  Person_ID
FROM    Exam_Result
WHERE   Exam_type = 'type_here'
GROUP   BY Person_ID
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN EXAM_RESULT = 'PASSED' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Students that not have passed the exam: either haven't taken it or failed all their's attempts */
/* All the students */
select distinct Person_id
  from Exam_Results

except /* this keyword is server dependent! MINUS for Oracle*/

/* Students that have passed */
select Person_Id
  from Exam_Results
 where (Exam_Result = 'passed') and
       (Exam_Type = 'my exam type')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I use Oracle.

Comment: @Dmitry If you use Oracle and you want an answer specifically for Oracle, you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: just change EXCEPT keyword to MINUS

Comment: @ypercube Ok, but I am interested in cross-db-answer, that is why I haven't tagged it =)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a head start, this is what you can do:

```
SELECT PersonId,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ExamResult = 'PASS' THEN 1 END) CNT
FROM ExamResults
WHERE ExamType = 'CONCRETE'
GROUP BY PersonId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ExamResult = 'PASS' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7702/3)